# jQuery sliders in PHP foreach issue

Tags: php, jquery, foreach, slider

I have a javascript problem, and I tried different solutions but I don't know how to resolve this issue right know, so, i'm asking you some help !

The aim of this code, is to present on a view, as much jQuery sliders as there are users.
I am using this jQuery slider : http://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemax

In my example, I have 6 users, the problem is that the JS doesn't enable to update the 'dailyAmount' input for each user when I moove the handle of the slider.
It works only for the last user, I assume that the JS code that remain active on the page is the one corresponding to the last iteration only..

Here is the code, I'm looking for a solution for days now, but I didn't find any discussion about that on the different communities.

I have this code (simplified to expose you the issue) :

> Start of the php code

```
<?php
$ii = 0;
foreach($userList as $user){
     $threshold = $user->getCurrentThreshold();
     $dailyThreshold = $threshold->getDailyThreshold();
     $dailySlider = "dailySlider".$ii;
     $dailyAmount = "dailyAmount".$ii;
     $weeklyAmountId = "weeklyAmount".$ii;
?>
```

> Javascript code to get the dynamic id for each iteration

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var sliderId = '#dailySlider'+<?php echo $ii; ?>;
                var dailyAmount = '#dailyAmount'+<?php echo $ii; ?>;
                 $(function() {
                     $(sliderId).slider({
                         range: "max",
                         min: 1,
                         max: 4,
                         value: <?php echo $dailyThreshold ?>,
                         slide: function( event, ui ) {
                            // alert(sliderId);
                            $(dailyAmount).val( ui.value );
                         }
                     });
                     $(dailyAmount).val( $(sliderId).slider( "value" ) );
                });
</script>
```

> HTML code

```
<div class="threshold">
     <form>
          <fieldset>
               <input type="text" id=<?php echo $dailyAmount ?>>
               <div id=<?php echo $dailySlider ?>></div>
          </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

> End of the PHP code, to increment $ii and close the foreach iteration

```
<?php>
$ii++;
}
?>
```

How can I have an active JS code to make the 'dailyAmount' in-real-time-updated by the slider when we moove the handle for each user ?

Thanx in advance for your suggestions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// you should have error reporting on.

// get $userList as usual...

$ii = 0; // funiest increment var i've seen. Also why don't you use the actual $user ID if you have it.
foreach($userList as $user) {
     $threshold = $user->getCurrentThreshold();
     $dailyThreshold = $threshold->getDailyThreshold();
     $dailySlider = "dailySlider".$ii;
     $dailyAmount = "dailyAmount".$ii;
     $weeklyAmountId = "weeklyAmount".$ii;

// using a data attribute for this made sense, and helps clean up the javascript.
?>
<div class="threshold" data-uid="<?php echo $ii; ?>">
     <form> <!-- i personally wouldn't put that many forms on the page, and do it with one but obviously I don't know what requirements you have -->
          <fieldset>
               <input class="amount" type="text" id="<?php echo $dailyAmount;?>">
               <div class="slider" id="<?php echo $dailySlider; ?>"></div>
          </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
    $ii++;
}

?>

Outside the loop..

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.threshold[data-uid]').each(function(index){
        var uid = $(this).attr('data-uid');
        var sliderId = '#dailySlider'+uid;
        var dailyAmount = '#dailyAmount'+uid;
             $(sliderId).slider({
                 range: "max",
                 min: 1,
                 max: 4,
                 value: <?php echo $dailyThreshold ?>,
                 slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    // alert(sliderId);
                    $(dailyAmount).val( ui.value );
                 }
             });
             $(dailyAmount).val( $(sliderId).slider( "value" ) );       
    });
});


</script>
```

I haven't tested it, but it should make sense.

Comment: Thanx for your answer, sadly, it doesn't change anything :/
I didn't know data-uid by the way, but it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: I think that my issue is due to the use of PHP var in JS : PHP is exectuted before JS, so, my JS var take the value of the last PHP var. I'm going in the wrong way and I know it, but I would clearly need a clue to resolve this !

Comment: ummm, no. you js vars are being declared outside of the js ready function so they are filled with the last iteration. It has nothing to  do with php. Please review my code. I am doing things very different.

Comment: OK ! This is working, thanx very much Anthony !

I found another solution, thanx to a dev friend ^^
with the code I showed you above, I was able to see every users sliders but the input was not updated in real time when I moved the handle of the slider, that was my problem.

I kept exactly the same code, but in the slider I replaced 

    slide: function( event, ui ) {
         $(dailyAmount).val( ui.value );
    }

by

    slide: function( event, ui ) {
         $(this).parent().children(".dailyAmount").val(ui.value);
    }

This is working very well too, I hope my problem will help others !